# how to get the Linkedin connections for users Linkedin profile using oAuth in android

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I am trying to get the connections for users profile in android.I have tried the following code.but it doesn't work out.I am getting an exception that "Access to connections denied". I am new to android,can u please help me out.

**LinkedinSampleActivity.java**

```
    public void getConnections(){

    Connections connections = client.getConnectionsForCurrentUser();
    Log.d("Connections",""+ connections.toString());
    //System.out.println("Total connections fetched:" + connections.getTotal());
    for (Person person : connections.getPersonList()) {
            System.out.println(person.getId() + ":" + person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getLastName() + ":" + person.getHeadline());
    }
  }
```

I have called this method in the same activity.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the APP settings in your developer LinkedIn account and make sure that you have enabled r_network checkbox in the OAuth Agreement.

Answer (score 0):

it seems from lastt May LinkedIn restricted its API call services, for example it's not possible anymore to get user's connections by calling API, see this: https://www.quora.com/Does-LinkedIns-API-allow-a-site-to-grab-a-users-contacts-information and this: https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/todays-changes